# There is something similar to MailTab for Ubuntu?

Tags: indicator, mac, apple

I was using Mac OS for some days and this app (MailTab) is really usefull:
http://screenshots.en.sftcdn.net/en/scrn/317000/317480/mailtab-for-gmail-5.jpg

Anyone know anything similar?

Comment: Can you add to the description which features are you looking for? There are several mail alerting for the system bar or indicator but perhaps not an useful alternative for you.

Comment: Actually I'm looking for the possibilities to open a browser Windows, so you can add any mobile site (as Gmail) to open directly from status bar.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be similar to what you're looking for.

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/154/gmail-notify/  This is for gnome 3, I'm not sure if there is something for unity..

Comment: It's good, but isn't what I'm looking for. :/